# Как сохранить(прочитать) в(из) файл json свойство "IsSelected" узла TreeView?

Tags: c#

Сохранить

```
// Сохранить в 
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            this.treeView1.Save(jsonFilePath);
        }
```

Прочитать

```
// Прочитать
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
            this.treeView2.Load(jsonFilePath);
        }
```

Класс **TreeRepository.cs**

```
public static class TreeRepository
    {
        public class DataNode
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
            // public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
            public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
            public bool IsSelected  { get; set; }
            public List<DataNode> Children { get; set; }
        }

        public static List<DataNode> LoadDataNodes(string jsonFilePath)
        {
            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
            var dataNodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataNode>>(json);
            return dataNodes;
        }

        public static void Load(this TreeView treeView, string jsonFilePath)
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Load(LoadDataNodes(jsonFilePath));
        }

        public static void Load(this TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<DataNode> dataNodes)
        {
            foreach (var dataNode in dataNodes)
            {
                var treeNode = nodes.Add(dataNode.Text);
                treeNode.Checked = dataNode.IsChecked;
                    treeNode.IsExpanded = dataNode.IsExpanded;
                if (dataNode.Children != null && dataNode.Children.Count > 0)
                {
                    Load(treeNode.Nodes, dataNode.Children);
                }

                if (dataNode.IsSelected)
                {
                    treeNode.IsSelected = true;
                } 
            }
        }



        public static List<DataNode> GetDataNodes(this TreeView treeView)
        {
            var dataNodes = new List<DataNode>();
            AddNodesToList(treeView.Nodes, dataNodes);
            return dataNodes;
        }

        private static void AddNodesToList(TreeNodeCollection nodes, List<DataNode> dataNodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
            {
                var dataNode = new DataNode
                {
                    Children = new List<DataNode>(),
                    IsChecked = node.Checked,
                    IsExpanded = node.IsExpanded,
                    IsSelected = node.IsSelected,
                    Text = node.Text
                };
                dataNodes.Add(dataNode);
                if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    AddNodesToList(node.Nodes, dataNode.Children);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void Save(this TreeView treeView, string jsonFilePath)
        {
            var dataNodes = treeView.GetDataNodes();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataNodes, Formatting.Indented);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(jsonFilePath, json);
        }


    }
```

В выражении

```
if (dataNode.IsSelected)
                    {
                        treeNode.IsSelected = true;
                    }
```

Ошибка
*CS0200 Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору "TreeNode.IsSelected" — доступ только для чтения.*

Как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, у нас есть тип данных для узла дерева

```
public class DataNode
{   
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }    
    [XmlElement("DataNode")]
    public List<DataNode> Nodes { get; set;} = new List<DataNode>();
}
```

И мы умеем его сериализовать \ десериализовать

```
public static void SerializeToFile<T>(T data, string filename)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.Serialize(sw, data);
    }
}

public static T DeserializeFromFile<T>(string fname) where T : class
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fname))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var data = ser.Deserialize(sr) as T;            
        return data;
    }
}
```

Пример XML файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfDataNode xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <DataNode Text="Node_1" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
  <DataNode Text="Node_2" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
  <DataNode Text="Node_3" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="true">
    <DataNode Text="Node_3_1" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
    <DataNode Text="Node_3_2" IsSelected="true" IsExpanded="true">
      <DataNode Text="Node_3_2_1" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
    </DataNode>
    <DataNode Text="Node_3_3" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="true">
      <DataNode Text="Node_3_3_1" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
    </DataNode>
    <DataNode Text="Node_3_4" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
    <DataNode Text="Node_3_5" IsSelected="false" IsExpanded="false" />
  </DataNode>
</ArrayOfDataNode>
```

Что нам надо, чтобы построить дерево по файлу? Нам нужен метод, что создаст само дерево (и заполнит верхний список узлов)

```
private static TreeView LoadTree(string fname)
{
    var data = DeserializeFromFile<DataNode[]>(fname);
    var tv = new TreeView();        

    foreach(var d in data)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode();
        tv.Nodes.Add(node);
        FillNode(tv, node, d);                      
    }   

    return tv;
}
```

И метод для загрузки дочерних узлов

```
private static void FillNode(TreeView tv, TreeNode node, DataNode d)
{   
    foreach(var c in d.Nodes)
    {
        var n = new TreeNode();
        FillNode(tv, n, c);
        node.Nodes.Add(n);
    }       

    node.Text = d.Text;
    if (d.IsExpanded) node.Expand();        
    if (d.IsSelected) tv.SelectedNode = node;       
}
```

Что нам надо для записи дерева в файл? Метод, что запишет верхний уровень

```
private static void SaveTree(string filename, TreeView tv)
{
    var data = new List<DataNode>();

    foreach(TreeNode node in tv.Nodes)
    {
        var dataNode = GetDataNode(node);
        data.Add(dataNode);
    }

    SerializeToFile(data, filename);
}
```

И метод, что заполнит дочерние узлы

```
private static DataNode GetDataNode(TreeNode node)
{
    var dataNode = new DataNode();
    dataNode.Text = node.Text;
    dataNode.IsExpanded = node.IsExpanded;
    dataNode.IsSelected = node.IsSelected;

    foreach(TreeNode n in node.Nodes)
    {
        var d = GetDataNode(n);
        dataNode.Nodes.Add(d);
    }

    return dataNode;
}
```

Все, это все, что нужно, чтобы написать приложение с сохранением\загрузкой дерева. Пример:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var fname = @"D:\temp\datanodes.xml";
        var tv = LoadTree(fname);
        this.Controls.Add(tv);

        this.Width = 300;
        this.Height = 250;
        tv.Width = 200;
        tv.Height = 200;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        var btnSave = new Button() { Text = "Save" };
        this.Controls.Add(btnSave);
        btnSave.Left = 200;
        btnSave.Click += (sender, args) => SaveTree(fname, tv);
    }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: вывод]

---

**upd**

Пропустил, что вам надо сериализовать в json. Но для этого в коде требуется минимум изменений - поправить функции сериализации\десериализации (я использую библиотеку [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json))

```
public static void SerializeToFile<T>(T data, string filename)
{
    File.WriteAllText(filename, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
}

public static T DeserializeFromFile<T>(string fname) where T : class
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(File.ReadAllText(fname));
}
```

Пример Json файла на выходе:

```
[{
    "Text": "Node_1",
    "IsSelected": false,
    "IsExpanded": true,
    "Nodes": [{
        "Text": "Node_1_1",
        "IsSelected": false,
        "IsExpanded": false,
        "Nodes": []
    }, {
        "Text": "Node_1_2",
        "IsSelected": true,
        "IsExpanded": false,
        "Nodes": []
    }]
}]
```

Все остальное по прежнему работает.